# Print Rows if End of Field Matches a String in AWK

Tags: csv, awk

I have a csv file and I am trying to print rows using awk if a certail field ends with a specific string. So for example, I have the below CSV file:

```
col1,col2,col3
1,abcd,.abcd_efg
2,efgh,.abcd
3,ijkl,.abcd_mno
4,mnop,.abcd
5,qrst,.abcd_uvw
```

This is the result I am seeking after:

```
2,efgh,.abcd
4,mnop,.abcd
```

But I am getting a different result. This is the awk command I am using:

```
 cat file.csv | awk -F"," '{if ($3 ~ ".abcd" ) print $0}'
```

and This is the result I am getting:

```
1,abcd,.abcd_efg
2,efgh,.abcd
3,ijkl,.abcd_mno
4,mnop,.abcd
5,qrst,.abcd_uvw
```

I event tried the below, but no matched is returned so it didn't work:

```
cat file.csv | awk -F"," '{if ($3 ~ ".abcd$" ) print $0}'
```

Any clue what the issue might be? Am I using the wrong expression to get this result?

**EDIT:** This is another command I tried where I tried Kent's solution, but it didn't work:

```
cat file.csv | awk -F"," '$3 ~ "[.]abcd"'
```

Answer (score 3):

- First of all the `cat` in `cat file|awk ...` is useless, just `awk ... file`
- Your input text has no single comma, how come you set `FS=","`?
- If you want to do exact String compare, use `$3 == "whatever"` instead of `$3 ~ /regex/`

So your codes could be changed into:

```
awk  '$3 == ".abcd"' file
```

- If you really love regex, and want to do it in regex match way:

  ```
  awk  '$3 ~ "[.]abcd$"' file
  ```

or

```
awk '$3 ~ /^[.]abcd$/' file
```

depends on what you required.

Comment: The file is a csv file and there are commas but I forgot to include them. I just edited my question and added them

Comment: BTW, I just tried your solution, and it didn't work. I set the FS="," and tried it with the regular expression but it didn't work. Perhaps it's because I am searching for a specific string at the end of a field?

Comment: @Dr.Bake `I just tried your solution,..` what you tried, is not my solution. Have you read my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You may modify your `awk` command as followed,

```
$ cat file.csv | awk '$3 ~ /\.abcd$/ {print $0}'
2    efgh .abcd
4    mnop .abcd
```

Brief explanation,

- `$3 ~ /.abcd$/`: if `$3` matches the regex `.abcd$`, print `$0`

According to your modified question, you may change the `awk` command to:

```
cat file.csv | awk -F, '$3 ~ /\.abcd$/ {print $0}'
```

Comment: the `. (dot)` means any character

Comment: Thanks. I modify it to `\.`.

Comment: @CWLiu: You don't need the `{print $0}` to be present. It is take care inherently

Comment: Thank you for your solution but the file is a csv file and I forgot to add commas in my question. I added them. I tried this solution but it just didn't work for me. Should this work when parsing csv files?

Comment: @Dr.Bake I have add the answer for your modified question.